# How to expose slf4j for Aspecs

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, slf4j, logback

So, what i am trying to do is to wrap all logging functions in an aspect that will dynamically decide where to log. it can log to the default logger that was obtain by `LoggerFactory.getLogger` or, i can do something else with it.

The problems are as follows:

1. Impossible to Aspect (logback) LoggerFactory -> Its final
2. Impossible to Aspect (logback) Logger -> its final and no default constructor
3. cannot create a bean out of org.slf4j.Logger its an interface.

I understand there might be a way to do that with pure AspectJ `<context:load-time-weaver/>`?
but it needs to come with a change to the running script of the application. i don't want that.

Does anyone have any other ideas on how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't there a getLogger() method with a String-param? This way you can log to any logger you like...

Comment: I am trying to make something a bit different, i am aware of the options. TY for the comment though